# represent a variable in twig using for loop

Tags: symfony, zend-framework2, twig

In my Service I return an array which looks like this:

```
$array = [
    'bible_anagram_word'    => $result->getBibleAnagramWord(),
    'word_1'                => $result->getWord1(),
    'word_2'                => $result->getWord2(),
    'word_3'                => $result->getWord3(),
    ...
    'word_22'               => $result->getWord22(),
    'word_23'               => $result->getWord23(),
    'word_24'               => $result->getWord24(),
    'word_25'               => $result->getWord25(),
    'Bible_verse_reference' => $result->getBibleVerseReference(),
    'Bible_verse_text'      => $result->getBibleVerseText(),
    'Bible_translation'     => $result->getBibleTranslation(),
];
```

How do I represent **document.word_##** in this **for** loop?

```
{% for i in 1..25 %}
    {{ document.word_ ~ i|slice(0,1) }}
{% endfor %}
```

In PHP this code is:

```
substr ( $this->document['word_'.$i] , 0 , 1 )
```

My unsuccessful attempts include:

- {{ document.word_ ~ i|slice(0,1) }}
- {{ (document.word_ ~ i)|slice(0,1) }}
- {{ 'document.word_ ~ i'|slice(0,1) }}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
{{ attribute(document, 'word_' ~ i) }}
```

More on [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)