# Concatenate String as Variable in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form that generates field per category, so if I have 5 categories, twig will generate 5 category field.

This array consist of 5 categories, so it will loop 5 times.

```
{% set categories = ['attraction', 'featured_artist', 'co_presentator', 'major_sponsor', 'minor_sponsor'] %}
```

I'll count the total category and deduct it by 1 for the use of for loop. We're using in array so it would be like 0,1,2,3.. etc.

```
{% set total_category = categories|count -1 %}
```

Now the looping starts here, I have a different column in database, called attraction_image, major_sponsor_image, featured_artist_image. So I have to count the total value in that field per category.

```
{% for i in 0..total_category %}

    <div class="increment-field-container" data-increment-host="{{ categories[i] }}">
        {% set total_field = details.attraction_image|explode|count %}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I concatenate string as variable,

We're calling the total of field like this

```
{% set total_field = details.attraction_image|explode|count %}
```

But I want to happen is,

```
{% set total_field = details.categories[i]_image|explode|count %}
```

Technically it would be incorrect:

[image]

I tried this String Interpolation thing, but still did not work.

```
{% set total_field = details."#{categories[i]}"_image|explode|count %}
```

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) for this. See my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507881/represent-a-variable-in-twig-using-for-loop/31508183#31508183) for details.

Comment: While waiting for an answer I'm reading into that documentation, and quite confused on it and here we go, you clarified on how to use it in other question. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually came accross this after figuring it out. But the way I got around this issue was as Richard pointed out, using the attribute method:

```
{% set field_1 = input_get('field_1') %}
{{attribute(blogs, field_1) }}
```

Whatever you have field_1 se as (for example 'layouts') it would equate to

```
blogs.layouts
```

Hope this helps!